# Checkbox in AJAX not Checking

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask-sqlalchemy

So I created a todo table in my database but strangely my list was not registering when I check it to change the False value to True. I tried to catch the error in the console log but don't know if I was not doing it well because it didn't print any error in the console only in the body that it was printing

> Something went wrong

> index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Todo App</title>
        <style>
        .hidden{
            display:none;
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description">
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>

        <div id="error" class="hidden">Something went wrong</div>
        <ul id="todo">
            {% for d in data %}
                <li><input class="check-completed" data-id="{{ d.id }}" type="checkbox" {% if d.completed %} checked {% endif %}/> {{d.description}}</li>
            {% endfor %}    
        </ul>

        <script>
            const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check-completed');
            for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                const checkbox = checkboxes[i];
                checkbox.onchange = function(e) {
                const newCompleted = e.target.checked;
                const todoId = e.target.dataset['id'];
                fetch('/todo/', + todoId + '/set-completed', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                    'completed': newCompleted
                    }),
                    headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                })
                .then(function() {
                    document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    document.getElementById('error').className = '';
                    console.error();
                })
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                fetch('/todo/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'description': document.getElementById('description').value
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(jsonResponse){
                    console.log(jsonResponse);
                    const liItem= document.createElement('LI');
                    liItem.innerHTML = jsonResponse['description'];
                    document.getElementById('todo').appendChild(liItem);
                    document.getElementById('error').className='hidden';
                })

                .catch(function(error){
                    document.getElementById('error').className = '';
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my app.py The backend is Python and I'm using flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:PassKey55@localhost:5432/todoapp'
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todo'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Todo {self.id} {self.description}>'

db.create_all()

@app.route('/todo/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    error = False
    body = {}
    try:
        description = request.get_json()['description']
        todo = Todo(description2=description)
        db.session.add(todo)
        db.session.commit()
        body['description'] = todo.description
    except:
        error = True
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_info())
    finally:
        db.session.close()
    if not error:
        return jsonify(body)
    # return jsonify({
    #     'description': todo.description
    # })


@app.route('/todo/<todo_id>/set-completed', methods=['POST'])
def set_completed_todo(todo_id):
    try:
        completed = request.get_json()['completed']
        print('completed', completed)
        todo = Todo.query.get(todo_id)
        todo.completed = completed
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
    finally:
        db.session.close()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data = Todo.query.all())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=3000)
```

Comment: The argument to the `.catch()` callback will be the error message. Try logging it to see why the fetch failed.

Comment: you have a comma after `'/todo/'`

Comment: @Musa  I got ':5000/favicon.ico:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)' after removing the comma

Comment: forget problem with `:5000/favicon.ico` - all browsers automatically try to load FavIcon to display it in title/tab but you can skip this problem. It has nothing to do with real problem in code.

Comment: you should run code in console to see all error messages with details. ANd you should show errors which you get in console.

Comment: `Something wrong` usually means problem in Python code and often it means problem with database. First you should check errors which you get in system console/terminal (not in JavaScript console)